# Determine if many-to-many record combination exists

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, innodb

This seems like it would be a common task with an easy solution but I've come up empty handed both on StackOverflow and Google.

Scenario is this: I have two tables A & B that share a many-to-many relationship.  As such I have table A_B with foreign keys which maps the A-to-B record relationships.  Standard stuff.

All I'm trying to figure out is how to query the tables before I enter a new record (one 'A' record with one or more 'B' records) if a matching, identical relationship already exists.  The goal is to not duplicate the data.

Finally, these tables will grow quite large so I need to keep overhead down where at all possible.

**UPDATE**

Below is an example query I was trying, to determine if there was an existing A record mapped to B_id values 3, 4, and 5.  It works, however it returns false positives if there are two different A_id values that span 3, 4, and 5, e.g.:

- A_id = 1, B_id values = 2, 3
- A_id = 2, B_id values = 4, 5, 6

```
SELECT A_id, B_id
FROM A_B
GROUP BY
A_id HAVING
    B_id IN (3,4,5)
    AND
    COUNT(*) = 3
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE 2**

<strike>The A_B table's primary key is a composite key including A_id and B_id</strike>.

The A_B table defines a unique composite key including A_id and B_id.

A single A is comprised of one or more Bs.

A more general way to phrase this question: given a finite set of B id values, I need to be able to determine if there is an existing A comprised of that exact set of Bs.  If not, a new A is created with that set of Bs.

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that even though the A_B relationship is many-to-many, only one A record is allowed to relate to a specific subset of B records?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked your question until just now.  That is correct.  Business logic dictates that A is comprised of 1 or more Bs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT to the rescue! Given B_id values 1, 3 and 5, here's how you (I) can determine if that unique combination exists and retrieve the corresponding A_id at the same time:

```
SELECT A_id FROM A_B
GROUP BY A_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(B_id) = '1,3,5';
```

No subqueries required, and may be optimized by adding a composite index A_id_B_id on the A_B table.

Thanks to participants who chimed in and ultimately steered me in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query the table to see if there are existing records?

```
$query = "SELECT * from tableA_B WHERE columnA = A"
$result = mysql_query($query);
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 1){
    //do something about having entries
}
```

You'll obviously have to replace the table and column names with the actual values as well as your search parameter for A.

Comment: That's what I'm asking how to do.  I will update my question from "how to determine" to "how to query the tables", I guess that's not clear.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about a unique relationship between a record in table A and multiple records in table B.  Your code doesn't address the issue.

Comment: @Madbreaks - if there is a certain value A that has multiple associated B records then the query will return all of the rows, each with a different B value but the same A value.  If there is only a one to one relationship at the time of the query then only one row will be returned.

Comment: @DShook - I think your approach is too much black and white: "can I insert all values? Or not a single". In fact there might be situiations like "insert 3, leave out 2 of them!"

Comment: @DShook - here's an example of two unique mappings: A=1, B=1,2  (and)  A=1, B=1,2,3.  These are different mappings, but your query treats them equally.

Comment: @Madbreaks - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the comma lists in B then.  A true many to many table would have records like A=1 B=1, A=1 B=2, A=1 B=3

Comment: @DShook - you say "would have", but really it's "could have".  In my case, each A is comprised of n Bs.  It's still a many-to-many relationship though because n As can have the same B, and one A can have n Bs.  Thank you for your continued efforts here BTW!

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* have foreign keys? There should be a way to declare this combination of table1.key-->table2.key unique. 
Which would result in a regular SQL error, when producing an already existing pair of entries. This is what i like about foraign keys. It's very clean, because the intelligence on (not)allowed entries stays on database level.

You have a table A_B containing assignments, don't you? 
A.id 88 belongs to B.id 99 ... etc.?

And you plan inserting ONE A-Record combined with n B-Records?
Why not - if new values are A=99 and B: 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 20

```
SELECT b_id
FROM A_B
WHERE a_id = 99
AND b_id IN (10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 20);
```

This will result in a list of b_ids you must not insert again ... OR an empty result (all entries are new).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I really do have foreign keys.  Yes, one A record to n B records.  The problem with your query is that, if there's a record A=99 and B records 10,11,12,17,18,20 *and 21*, the query will return a false positive.  The B id values must be unique.  I added more to my question, perhaps it will help clarify.

Comment: @Heiko, one more thing, you said "There should be a way to declare this combination of table1.key-->table2.key unique".  That would break the many-to-many relationship shared between tables A and B.

Comment: UNIQUE for the foreign key would not mean unique entries in A and B, but unique combinations of A->B. 
I dont' get the problem with existing 21 if you intend to add 10,11,12,17,18,20. 

If A=99 --> B=10,11,12,17,18,20, **21** exist, your result will be [10,11,12,17,18,20] the values you should not insert.

Maybe theres' still something I misunderstood?

Comment: @Heiko - Eesh, unique A<-->B correct.  The A_B table's two columns comprise its primary key. Sorry. The issue is we don't know "99".  We only know "here's a new set of B values.  Is there an existing A comprised of these and only these B values?"  I will update my original question.

Comment: OK, now I understand your SQL statement in your question. 
But it provides A-values that are combined with 3 or 4 or 5, because count(*) refers to the outer query.
should be no problem with a subselect. Thinking about something without, subselects suck!

Comment: another question. Is A=1 -> B=1,2,3 and A=2 -> B=3,4,5 allowed? Your primary key A->B would say NO when inserting A=1 with B=3.

Comment: @Heiko - Agreed, subselects suck.  :)  And yes to your second question, that should be allowed..I need to update my table schema.  Excellent catch, thanks very much (updating my original question to reflect this).

Comment: @Heiko - any further thoughts on this?  I was able to get it working with a simple subquery but performance wise it's not a viable solution due to the amount of data that will be involved.

Comment: @Heiko - added a solution in original question

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() ...  great! quite useful and good to know. Thanks for posting your solution!